# ASP.Net Post User control Post to new page

Tags: c#, asp.net, user-controls

I am creating a custom user control that will act as a search feature.  I want to easily be able to add this to multiple pages without having to modify much code.

I thought the best method to do this would be to create a simple user control that I can inject anywhere with one line of code and then have this control postback to a different URL.  So wherever the search function is, it will always post back to the same page.  My control looks like this:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="searchTextBox" runat="server" MaxLength="350"></asp:TextBox>
<asp:Button ID="submit" runat="server" Text="Search" PostBackUrl="~/myPostBackPage.aspx" />
```

myPostBackPage.aspx.cs looks like this, but it isn't grabbing the text.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    content.InnerHtml = ((TextBox)PreviousPage.FindControl("searchTextBox")).Text;
}
```

But it isn't pulling anything from the searchTextBox field and I get:

```
Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
```

Is there a better way to do this or how should I fix my code?  Thanks!

Comment: How about passing text box value as query string to the myPostBack.aspx page?

Comment: you should look into the OnClosing() as well

Comment: I imagine that would work for this case since I am simply retrieving data.  I would still like to know how to post to another page though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know where the `TextBox` is declared, if you for example use MasterPages the `NamingContainer` of it would be the `ContentPlaceHolder` of the master instead of the Page. Therefore just cast the `PreviousPage` property to the correct type:

```
YourPageType page = PreviousPage as YourPageType;
if(page != null)
{
    content.InnerHtml = page.SearchText;
}
```

You have to provide a public property since the `TextBox` is protected(best-practise anyway):

```
public string SearchText
{
    get {  return searchTextBox.Text;  }
}
```

Comment: The TextBox is declared in my ascx user control.  I am working within Master Pages, but the user control is just added into my ContentPlaceHolder of another page.

Comment: When attempting to do it this way, there is no definition for 'searchTextBox'

Comment: @jpsnow72: Yes, because it's in a `UserControl` and not in the page itself. I assume the `NamingContainer` is the `UserControl`, but that won't help you much in this scenario since you want to use the control on different pages. You could try to get it from the [`Request.Form` variables](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest.form(v=vs.110).aspx) although that would be cumbersome.

Comment: When adding the public property to my ASCX.cs I still get:  'System.Web.UI.Page' does not contain a definition for 'SearchText'

Comment: @jpsnow72: You haven't casted the page to your type(as shown above). But as i've already said in my last comment, i'm afraid this approach will not help you much since you want to reuse the `UserControl` on different pages.

Comment: I tried previousPage.Request.Form["searchTextBox"]; with no luck... where previous page is Page previousPage = PreviousPage

Comment: Ok. Thanks.  It looks like I might be stuck putting it into the querystring.

Answer (score 0):

I tested your code and **PreviousPage** is null. Try switch to **Page**.